# How to populate deploy_to variable with custom server property

Tags: ruby, capistrano

I've asked this question on Capistrano's GitHub repository issue tracker (https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/1750) and was told to ask the same question here.

I'm trying to populate the deploy_to variable with a custom server property (named organisation) to deploy the same application multiple times to the same server.

```
set :deploy_to, "/home/deploy/sites/#{server.properties.organisation}"
```

It seems impossible to load the server Array? using the fetch() method.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a couple different things for this case. If each installation is indeed identical, I'll deploy once and symlink the other installations. If each installation has different parameters, I'll create multiple targets (prod-1, prod-2, prod-2, et cetera) where each points at the same server. You can use helper methods to reduce code duplication. Then I'll write a script which runs `bundle exec cap prod-1 deploy && bundle exec cap prod-2 deploy && ...`.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing right now as a workaround. It does feel like a quick hack and defeats the purpose of a multi server deployment tool. There has to be a better solution...

Comment: Another hack might be to use multiple CNAMEs as deployment targets, all of which refer to the same server.